# Accessing an externed variable from objective-c in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2, objective-c-swift-bridge

I have an iOS project that uses both Obj-C and Swift.

In `main.m`, I want to instantiate a variable to be accessed by Swift. The specific use case is to store the absolute time at `main`, and then measure time elapsed since `main` elsewhere.

Here's what my relevant files look like:

`main.m`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

CFAbsoluteTime StartTime;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    StartTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent(); // This is what I want to access elsewhere.
    @autoreleasepool {
        ...
    }
}
```

`myapp-Bridging-Header.h`

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
extern CFAbsoluteTime StartTime;
```

`AppDelegate.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

extern CFAbsoluteTime StartTime;

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>{}

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIWindow* window;
// ... other irrelevant @property

@end
```

And then in the actual `.swift` file, I'm just trying to access `StartTime` without declaring anything (as I thought it worked since it's being externed), but I'm getting an `unresolved identifier` error.

Comment: FYI, if you have `extern` declaration in your `.h` file that you're importing in your bridging header, you don't need to repeat `extern` declaration again in the bridging header file, itself. Bottom line, the above works fine for me. I wonder if your bridging header is being read at all. You might want to double check the build settings where bridging header is set. Can you see `AppDelegate` class from Swift, too? That's an easy way to check that the bridging header is being picked up properly...

Comment: Ah, for some reason there were 2 bridging headers, and the one shown in xcode was not the one in build settings. That fixed it.